# Find largest unsigned int .... Why doesn't this work?

Tags: c++

Couldn't you initialize an unsigned int and then increment it until it doesn't increment anymore? That's what I tried to do and I got a runtime error "Timeout." Any idea why this doesn't work? Any idea how to do it correctly?
    #include

```
int main() { 

    unsigned int i(0), j(1);
    while (i != j) {
       ++i;
       ++j;
    }
    std::cout << i;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What makes you think the increment will just stop working once you reach the limit? It's more likely to wrap to 0, although I'm not sure if this is defined behavior.

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Of course, you could just say `unsigned int i = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();`.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9016741/10077

Comment: It wont work the way you are expecting. The behaviour in this case in not undefined (not that it will stop incrementing). Refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016741/behavior-of-increment-operator-at-bounds-for-char-type

Comment: @juanchopanza Or `unsigned int i = -1;`.

Comment: Rather than testing (in)equality, if you want to handle the case where the number wraps-around, you should test the condition that one number is always greater than the other. ***That*** test will fail after you hit the largest value.

Answer (score 4):

Unsigned arithmetic is defined as modulo 2^n in C++ (where n is
the number of bits).  So when you increment the maximum value,
you get `0`.

Because of this, the simplest way to get the maximum value is to
use `-1`:

```
unsigned int i = -1;
std::cout << i;
```

(If the compiler gives you a warning, and this bothers you, you
can use `0U - 1`, or initialize with `0`, and then decrement.)

Comment: So change `while (i !=j)` to `while (i < j)` and it should work. `std::numeric_limits` is a better idea, though.

Comment: @FredLarson `std::numeric_limits` has the advantage that it will work with any type, not just unsigned types.  Just converting `-1` to the proper type is guaranteed for unsigned types, however, and is probably the most idiomatic solution.

Comment: Simplest way to get the maximum value is `~0` (For general unsigned type: `~(type)0`).  There should be no compiler warning.  And `-(1U)` should also work (in general: `-(type)1`).

Comment: @BenVoigt `~0` only works if you convert it to the proper type first.  `-1` works without the explicit conversion.  (In other words: `unsigned long i = -1;` results in the largest unsigned long; `unsigned long i = ~0;` doesn't, at least not on machines where `long` is larger than `int`.  And I suspect that a lot less programmers are familiar with the subtleties of `~` than with `-`.

Comment: @James: your suggestion of `0U - 1` is always the same result as `~0U`, isn't it?

Comment: @BenVoigt `0U -1` and `~0U`, yes.  Using `-1` directly as initializer, no.  The important point is that `-1` is still a signed integer when it is converted to the target type (e.g. `unsigned long long`, for example), and converts directly to the target type.  In `0U - 1` or `~0U`, you end up with a value that is `UINT_MAX`, which is then converted to the target type.  (Interestingly enough, on a 2's complement machine, `~0`, with a signed `int` type, works, regardless of the target type.  It will result in a wrong value on 1's complement or signed magnitude, however.)

Comment: Right.  And `~0ULL` will fill any standard unsigned type with the maximum value, although I expect it generates a compiler warning just like `-1`.  Bit-wise complement of 0 of the correct type is the shortest code with no warning.

Comment: @BenVoigt And for initialization, `-1` works without worrying about the type.  (I'd also argue that it's the most idiomatic, since it's what the standard does, e.g. for `std::basic_string<>::npos`.  But I suspect what's most idiomatic will actually vary between shops.)

Answer (score 1):

Since `i` will **never** be equal to `j`, you have an infinite loop.

Additionally, this is a **very** inefficient method for determining the maximum value of an  `unsigned int`.  `numeric_limits` gives you the result without looping for 2^(16, 32, 64, or however many bits are in your `unsigned int`) iterations.  If you didn't want to do that, you could write a much smaller loop:

```
unsigned int shifts = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; // or CHAR_BITS
unsigned int maximum_value = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < shifts; ++i)
{
    maximum_value <<= 1;
    ++maximum_value;
}
```

Or simply do

```
unsigned int maximum = (unsigned int)-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` will always be different than `j`, so you have entered an endless loop. If you want to take this approach, your code should look like this:

```
unsigned int i(0), j(1);
while (i < j) {
   ++i;
   ++j;
}
std::cout << i;

return 0;
```

Notice I changed it to `while (i<j)`. Once `j` overflows i will be greater than `j`.

When an overflow happens, the value doesn't just stay at the highest, it wraps back abound to the lowest possible number.

Answer (score 0):

i and j will be never equal to each other. When an unsigned integral value achieves its maximum adding to it 1 will result in that the next value will be the minimum that is 0. 
For example if to consider unsigned char then its maximum is 255. After adding 1 you will get 0.

So your loop is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't you initialize an unsigned int and then increment it until it doesn't increment anymore?

No. Unsigned arithmetic is modular, so it wraps around to zero after the maximum value. You can carry on incrementing it forever, as your loop does.

> Any idea how to do it correctly?

```
unsigned int max = -1;  // or
unsigned int max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

or, if you want to use a loop to calculate it, change your condition to `(j != 0)` or `(i < j)` to stop when `j` wraps. Since `i` is one behind `j`, that will contain the maximum value. Note that this might not work for signed types - they give undefined behaviour when they overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to find the maximum limit that an unsigned integer can store (which is 65,535 in decimal). The reason that the program will time out is because when the int hits the maximum value it can store, it "Goes off the end." The next time j increments, it will be 65,535; i will be 0.

This means that the way you're going about it, i would NEVER equal j, and the loop would run indefinitely. If you changed it to what Damien has, you'd have i == 65,535; j equal to 0.