# Increment of character in C

Tags: c, char, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    char c=127;

    do
      count++;
    while(c++);
    printf("count=%d ",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why after the first loop, the value of c will become to -128?

Comment: Because `char` is an 8-bit signed type. Using 2s complement, 127 is represented as 0x7F, and -128 is represented as 0x80. When incrementing 0x7F (127), we get 0x80 (-128).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behavior of increment operator at bounds for char type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016741/behavior-of-increment-operator-at-bounds-for-char-type)

Comment: @barakmanos: [`char` actually has undefined signedness by the standard.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/364696). That's why I was careful to note in my answer that this was a choice by his compiler. It's usually signed, but compiler flags can change it to unsigned, and either interpretation is standard legal.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I actually think it's a shame that the language standard does not impose `sign`/`unsigned` next to every integral type, and on the other hand, allows declarations like `unsigned` (synonymous to `unsigned int`), `short int` (synonymous to `short`), and several other different forms like `long int`, `long long int`, etc. Not sure why they didn't take their time to come up with a minimal and concise set of (simple) rules, and in exchange, left all this ambiguity behind...

Comment: Should this be read as "while there is c++, no good outcome is possible"? :)

Comment: *Can anybody explain to me why after the first loop, the value of c will become to -128?*: how do you know that?  I see `count=130` whether `char` is signed or not, albeit not guaranteed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your compiler defaults `char` to `signed char`. So the range of values for it is -128 to 127, and incrementing 127 is triggering wraparound. If you want to avoid this, be explicit, and declare your variable as `unsigned char`.

Mind you, to do this correctly, you also want to change the `printf`; you're printing as a signed `int` value (`%d`); to be 100% type correct, you'd want to match types, so the format code should be `%hhd` for a signed char, or `%hhu` for an unsigned char. `%d` will work due to promotion rules with varargs, but it's a bad habit to just use `%d` all the time; when you print an `unsigned` with `%d`, your system will likely succeed, but it will show large values as being negative, confusing you.

Comment: Please note that signed integer overflow is actually undefined behavior. Wrap-around is not guaranteed. The program might as well halt and catch fire or seemingly work as expected.

Comment: [AFAIK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8010063/4944425), not even a two's complement representation is guarateed by the standard...

Answer (score 2):

Another easy explanation of this problem

This situation is known as overflow of signed char. 
Range of unsigned char is `-128 to 127`. If we will assign a value greater than 127 then value of variable will be changed to a value if we will move clockwise direction as shown in the figure according to number. If we will assign a number which is less than -128 then we have to move in anti-clockwise direction.

When variable value is 127 then it's ok. But if variable value increment by 1 then clock wise increment also 1 and it's position value -128. So your output  is -128.

[image: Demo Image]

[Demo Link](http://www.cquestions.com/2010/10/c-interview-questions-and-answers.html#Exlink16)

Comment: Nice explanation and easily understand

Answer (score 1):

try using unsigned char to count up to 255

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It is a valid comment however.